# Баг при запуске с клавиатурой

Tags: java, android, kotlin, клавиатура, запуск

Допустим, если вбить в поиск лаунчера название моей программы, то она попадает наверх, откуда ее можно запустить не сворачивая клавиатуру. Однако, если не свернуть клавиатуру, то половина экрана, где была клавиатура, становится белой, а приложение жмется в оставшуюся часть экрана. Подобный же баг есть еще в VK X.

Как пофиксить?
Например, добавить в `OnCreate` метод, который будет сворачивать клавиатуру, но как?

Answer (score 0):

Если что баг был как-то связан с прошивкой, а конкретно AOSP 5.1. Ну или с лончером Lawnchair. В любом случае фикса я не нашел, он пропал когда я купил новый телефон)

Comment: То есть, как я понял, предложенный ответ вы не пробавали и ничего не можете сказать, полезный он или нет.  Это так?

Comment: Приношу извинения, не заметил, что другой ответ только что дан. Посмотрите его пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить в `onPostCreate()`:

```
private void hideSoftInput() {
    try { 
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```